# element does not exist in type in ReactJs+TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
   const listValuesAbout: Array<[string, string]> = [
     ['Other', 'Other'],
     ['Hello', 'Hello'],
   ]      
   //listValuesXelements/Contact have the same format than listValuesAbout

   export const DetailAboutValues = fromNameLabels(listValuesAbout)
   export const DetailContactValues = fromNameLabels(listValuesContact)
   export const DetailXelementsValues = fromNameLabels(listValuesXelements)

   const DetailPageInfoValues = fromNameLabels(
     listValuesHome
    .concat(listValuesAbout)
    .concat(listValuesContact)
    .concat(listValuesXElements)
   )
    const DetailPageInfo = fromLabelledEnum(DetailPageInfoValues)
    export type DetailPageInfo = keyof typeof DetailPageInfo
    
    type Page = "home" | "about" | "contact" | "xelements"
    
    const nav: Record<Page, LabelledEnum<DetailPageInfo>[]>> = {
      about: DetailAboutValues,
      contact: DetailContactValues,
      home: DetailXelementsValues,
      xelements: DetailXelementsValues,
    }
```

My problem is *xelements* does not exist in type *Record<xelements | "home" | "about" | "contact", LabelledEnum<...>[]>* but btw you can see him in type Page... how to apply typescript in my situation?